# Unusual behaviour of Spring form

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, post

**Requirement**: To avoid control going to onSubmit() in Spring 2.5

In a Controller if we have formBackingObject(), showForm() and onSubmit();

Suppose I have field

```
<form:input path="command.name">

<button onclick="cancelEditingForm()">Cancel</button>
```

**Now I followed few steps:**

1)I fill wrong input input then my validator will give error message.

2)And now if I refresh page then also request is going to onSubmit();

How I can avoid this?

Comment: Please let me know if more code is required.But I didn't elaborated because code is fine and it is general behaviour for all pages with error and refresh mechanism.

Comment: is onSubmit a java function or a javascript function?

Comment: This is probably happening because you are making an ajax call which is asynchronous and does not change the page(which keeps the state/response after submit).

Comment: @eis only cancelEditingForm is js function. Rest are the methods related to Spring

Comment: @Priyesh But suppose I didn't cancel and I refresh then also control goes to onSubmit(). Sorry ajaxMethod created confusion.